# backbone with requirejs : View and subviews and r.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, optimization

I have a view that requires requires Backbone, Undescore, jquery etc.

example

```
define(['jquery','undescore','backbone','subviewA', 'subviewB'], function($,_,Backbone, SubviewA, SubviewB){
   var View = Backbone.View.extend({
       //other methods here
       render : function() {
           this.subviewA = new SubviewA();
           this.subviewA.render(); 
           this.subviewB = new SubviewB();
           this.subviewB.render();
           return this; 
       }
   });
});
```

subview example

```
define(['jquery','undescore','backbone','text!templates/subviewA'], function($,_,Backbone, template){
   var SubviewA = Backbone.View.extend({
       //other methods here
       render : function() {
           this.$el.html(template);
           return this; 
       }
   });
});
```

My question is if I need to include jquery, undescore and backbone in the subviews too ir I can omit them?

**EDIT**

I am asking cause in r.js I need every time to tell it to not to biuld those dependencies inside each module.

Comment: Can you paste the code for one of your `SubView` modules, please?  You should just be able to list the dependencies just as you did above.

Comment: You don't need jquery and underscore in this view, but probably need at least jquery in your subviews. In general you need a requirement on something you directly use in that model or view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, if you don't use the $ or _ symbols in your views, you don't need to list jquery and underscore as direct dependencies of your module (whether it is a view or a subview doesn't change that).
You do need to include backbone though, since you reference it directly with : Backbone.View. If you want to be absolutely sure that the Backbone symbol is defined you should declare it as a dependency.

Some libs register themselves both as AMD modules and as global variables (typically jquery does that). Backbone doesn't support AMD directly and registers itself at the global level regardless of how it is used. In theory you could not declare it as a dependency, but then you have the risk that require will try and load the script before backbone is loaded in which case the Backbone symbol will not be defined.

It doesn't matter much if you redondantly declare the dependencies except for the additional caracters, thus the additional script size.

Comment: I am asking that cause when I use r.js I need to remove those dependencies cause it will build them inside each module

Comment: Are you sure you are using it right ? it sounds like you optimise js files instead of the whole project http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject

Answer (score 0):

You can omit any requirements which aren't used.

In your examples (ignoring omitted code!), you can remove `jquery` and `undescore` (sic) but **not** `backbone` (since you use it via `Backbone.View.extend`).

Obviously you need to keep your requirement names and variables in sync.

Comment: I still use the but wont they be availalbe as variables from the parent view?

Comment: Not unless you have a really weird file structure that you haven't shown us, no.